# AWS Athena: varchar maximum value not matched with query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I created Athena with this query\

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS report (                      
    `token` varchar(40),                                                               
)                                        
PARTITIONED BY ( `created_hour` string)                                        
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'                                        
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (                                          
    'serialization.format' = '1'                                        
) LOCATION 's3://demo-kinesis-athena/'                                        
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'has_encrypted_data'='false',                             
    'projection.created_hour.format' = 'yyyy/MM/dd/HH',                             
    'projection.created_hour.interval' = '1',                             
    'projection.created_hour.interval.unit' = 'HOURS',                             
    'projection.created_hour.range' = '2018/01/01/00,NOW',                             
    'projection.created_hour.type' = 'date',                             
    'projection.enabled' = 'true',                             
    'storage.location.template' = 's3://demo-kinesis-athena/${created_hour}'
);
```

The query run successfully and the table is created, but if I generate table DDL it gives me the column type to be

```
`token` varchar(65535)`
```

instead.

Comment: How are you generating the table DDL? and what is the output of the first query? Use [`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/show-create-table.html) and also add the output of that command to the question too please.

Comment: I clicked on the interface, right next to the table name, in Amazon Athena > Query Editor. SHOW CREATE TABLE `report`;